# is there a way to add part of code to nodejs implicitly?

Tags: node.js

I want to give the user the right to add a small part of code (if else) to the main code through website. is that possible ? if yes plz give me some keyword. I don't know what to search for

Comment: I guess my way of asking is so bad. I meant by my question: I want to do something like IFTTT by giving the user the possibility to create his own small code or script

Answer (score 0):

You can search for Node JS role management or "how to manage user's role/permission in Node JS" . You will get some tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to run some node.js code, you can look for packages such as [vm2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vm2), [isolated-vm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/isolated-vm) or the native node.js [vm](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html) module.

Those are all modules that allow you to create a separate node.js process with restrictive access (that you can define), so that you can run some code. Be careful those are not absolutely safe and can be escaped.

If your goal is to run some untrusted code, I think the best is to run it with a user with restricted rights, or use a `chroot` if you have control over your server.

Comment: I am trying to do a small home automation system using Nodejs. I want to add to the client (webpage) a way to give the user the possibility to add a small script like "if Motion Sensor detect motion then turn ON light" and I don't know where to start. Thank you for your suggestions, I am going to give them a look